# Remove MacBook from Apple ID, is extended warranty still valid after that?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, warranty

I want to sell my old Retina MacBook.

I know [how to erase/reinstall the Retina MackBook](https://discussions.apple.com/message/18872193#18872193), but two more questions remain:

1. How can I unregister it from my Apple ID?
2. Is the extended Apple Care Warranty still valid after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just logout (and install it from scratch after format) or check [this Kb](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627)
2. Apple Care is bought for a device, so yes.